# having trouble invoking edge browser thru Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

This is my code so I can test edge browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service
service_obj = service("C:\\Users\\svk11\\edgedriver_win64.exe")
driver = webdriver.edge(service=service_obj)
```

And I am getting this error.  Same code with changes, worked with chrome.

```
service_obj = service("C:\\Users\\svk11\\edgedriver_win64.exe")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciate
Thanks

I used above code but with info about Chrome...and I was able call the Chrome browser for testing
When I tweaked the code to invoke edge and Firefox browsers, I am getting
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase `service` is a module. Within the `service` module there is a class `Service` with an uppercase `S`. There is a similar problem with the way you are calling `webdriver.edge`

Try

```
service_obj = service.Service("C:\\Users\\svk11\\edgedriver_win64.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service_obj)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Naum.  It worked finally.  Had to retype the code starting with invoking webdriver.Edge.  Am going to try same with Firefox.  Hoping it will work.  Thanks again